# Mysql get records or data by monthly

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to write a MySQL query to get records by monthly for example:

Starting from the current month:

```
----- Jan -----
Record 1
Record 2
----- Feb -----
Record 1
Record 2
----- March-----
Record 1
Record 2
```

I have starting and ending timestamp and start_date, end_date(MM/DD/YYYY format) column in my db table.

Comment: Yes. Please research `group by`

Comment: No. Issues of data display are best resolved in application code

Comment: can you share what you have tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by getting start date & end date of month

```
$month_start_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-01', $timestamp)." 00:00:00"); 
$month_end_time   = strtotime(date('Y-m-t', $timestamp)." 23:59:59"); 
$sdate = date('d', $month_start_time); 
$edate = date('d', $month_end_time);
$j=0; 
for($k=$sdate; $k <= $edate; $k++){
  $start_date = $k.date('/m/Y', $month_start_time);        
  $stimestamp = strtotime(date('Y/m', $month_start_time).'/'.$k." 00:00:00"); 
  $end_date   = strtotime(date('Y/m', $month_start_time).'/'.$k." 23:59:59"); 
  //then pass in mysql query
}
```